# Redis master slave replication network latency

Tags: redis

which network delay is acceptable for Redis master-slave replication? Which network latency is acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

It's a complex mix of the number of write operations, the size of the write operations and the number of operations on the master.  The very short answer is keep the replicas as close a possible to the master.

You can observe the replica flushing and issuing a full resync command when you have exceeded the capacity of the replication.

You can also tune the [replication buffers](https://redis.com/blog/top-redis-headaches-for-devops-replication-buffer/) if the latency between the two nodes is high to mitigate any issues.

Comment: Thanks, we have tune Replication Buffers.